# Web site no longer displays and has been replaced by a page containing only "Index of..."

Tags: web-hosting, dns, 404

I have a web site hosted on a VPS that was working correctly until a few weeks ago.  This domain is used primarily for email and that still works as it did previously.  However, attempting to reach the web site from a browser now results in a page displaying "Index of /" as if there were no index.html file. There are files there, including the index.html file, but the page lists no files.  However, the files can be seen and manipulated through FTP.

Since the site typically just redirects to another site, I was unaware of the problem until Let'sEncrypt attempted to renew the SSL certificate and now I get multiple emails each day detailing the errors Let'sEncrypt receives when trying to validate for SSL renewal on the web site.

Accessing my domain with `http://example.com` gives the above result.  Trying `http://example.com/index.html` returns a 404  Not Found error.

The redirect has been removed with no change in results.

Checking the server's error log for this domain reveals 'script not found' errors, but they reference scripts not expected to be found and also 'AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation' errors. (Might that be related to Let'sEncrypt's attempts to validate SSL?).

It's like the DNS now points to something other than the correct server, but all DNS records seem to be there and correct (A and AAAA pointing to the proper IP addresses). TXT records were added in the recent past for DMARC and DKIM. These were added to insure email sent from this domain would not be bounced back.  Could they affect the web sites ability to serve pages?

What should I be looking for that might cause this situation?  Is there any other data I could provide that would be helpful?

**UPDATE:**

Ran domain test at Zonemaster and although no errors, received the following warnings:

> ADDRESS    warning     Nameserver ns1.dns-parking.com has an IP address (2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9) without PTR configured.

> ADDRESS    warning     Nameserver ns2.dns-parking.com has an IP address (2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:192a) without PTR configured.

> CONNECTIVITY   warning     All authoritative nameservers have their IPv4 addresses in the same AS (13335).

> CONNECTIVITY   warning     All authoritative nameservers have their IPv6 addresses in the same AS (13335).

> CONNECTIVITY   warning     The following name server(s) are announced in the same IPv6 prefix (2400:cb00:2049::/48): "ns1.dns-parking.com/2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9; ns2.dns-parking.com/2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:192a"

Also tests at dnsviz:
Here are the errors:

> wannabesports.com zone: The server(s) responded over TCP with a malformed response or with an invalid RCODE. (2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9)

> wannabesports.com/AAAA: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (162.159.24.201, UDP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_KN)

> wannabesports.com/DNSKEY: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (162.159.25.42, 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9, UDP_-_EDNS0_512_D_KN)

> wannabesports.com/MX: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (162.159.24.201, 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9, UDP_-*EDNS0_4096_D_KN, UDP*-_EDNS0_512_D_KN)

> wannabesports.com/SOA: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (162.159.24.201, UDP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_KN)

> wannabesports.com/SOA: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:18c9, TCP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_N)

Does the above indicate problems with the nameserver or incompatibility of some sort with settings between the site and the nameserver?

Comment: Anything change in the web server configuration that might point the document root to an unexpected directory?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with permissions since you say index.html exists however you can't access it.

Comment: Document root is still pointing to .../public_html which is the location of index.html.

Comment: The permissions for index.html are set to 0644 which corresponds to files on a known working server.

Comment: As you make a request, do you see that request recorded in the server's access log?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller - Attempting to load the site in a browser does NOT result in any log update.

Comment: Then the request isn't making it to the right server somehow. You should recheck your DNS records. You're using a CDN you should also check that.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller - updated the original post with some data from online DNS tests.  Also, what is CDN?  I've gone over and over the DNS records but find nothing that is obviously a problem.  As stated earlier, DKIM and DMARC records were added in the recent past to alleviate SMTP errors.  Could they be interfering somehow?

Comment: When I visit your site, I get a redirect to `https://wannabe-fantasysports.com/games/cgi-bin/ws_main.pl` which then gives me an error because it doesn't support HTTPS.  Is that the redirect you are expecting?  Maybe you have something in your `hosts.txt` or `/etc/hosts` on the machine you are testing with that causes it to fail locally?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller - The index.html is designed to redirect to that url except not a secure (https) url, just http.  So, I do not know how the 's' got in there.  But obviously you must have reached the site where I do not. Even trying several different browsers on 2 different computers (same local network) and an android phone not on that network.  I have 2 other domains on the same remote server as the problem one and no difficulty accessing them.  All my local computers are Windows machines and I can find no hosts.txt or /etc/hosts.  How can we get different results visiting the same site?

Comment: My browser is set to always use HTTPS (a setting in Firefox), so that explains the error.

Comment: If you install `dig` from bind, you can try commands like `dig wannabesports.com` and `dig NS wannabesports.com`  and `dig @ns1.dns-parking.com wannabesports.com` and `dig @ns2.dns-parking.com wannabesports.com` to make sure that you DNS is set up properly.  It all looks OK to me when I run those commands.

Comment: If you install `curl` you can run a command to force it to fetch from the correct IP address.  Doing that will make sure that the web server is functioning as you expect from your location and confirm that there is some DNS issue.  `curl --resolve wannabesports.com:443:153.92.214.61  https://wannabesports.com/`

Comment: Just to make sure you are looking in the right place, on Windows, your hosts file is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I can offer little insight into the hows and whys but this problem was fixed by simply deleting the AAAA (ipv6) record from the DNS data.  Thank you so much to Stephen Ostermiller for his extremely helpful advice which pointed to the action which ultimately solved the problem.

A brief description of the thought process. Following Stephen's advice to use the `curl` command noting the result could confirm a DNS problem, narrowed possibilities to DNS.  Researching other questions at this site, led to using `tracert` and finding it returned what appeared to be ipv6 addresses (also received ipv6 addresses in many of the errors quoted above from dnsviz and zonemaster sites).  Other, much older posts referenced problems with ipv6 in rare instances.  So, the AAAA record of the DNS for this site was simply deleted.  The result - problem fixed.